# AfterInsert Trigger on ContentVersion addError not working

Tags: trigger, contentversion, contentdocument

In Apex using a AfterInsert Trigger on ContentVersion (cv) object, the method `cv.addError ('Custom message')` is not working as expected.

Instead of showing the custom error message the error that is showing is just standard error and provide no information about the error.

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.new) {
        System.debug(cv.Title+' : ' +cv.ContentSize);
        if(cv.ContentSize > 5242880){
            cv.addError('You can\'t upload files with size more than 5MB.');
        }
    }
}
```

There is a [similar question in the Dev community](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QvrzQAC) (Trigger on ContentDocumentLink) but no answer.

Comment: Yeah!! If you building a Lightning component for content management, I think it should be handled from UI side rather than the trigger.

Comment: @sarveshkumar I am using `lightning:fileUpload`, and I couldn't find any attribute regarding restricting files based on size. Any idea how to implement without trigger?

Comment: Use onuploadfinished event, Please see the document.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation

Comment: @sarveshkumar onuploadfinished triggered when files have finished uploading.so I can't use this to restrict the upload.

Comment: Please follow this question [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325067/maximum-file-size-with-lightninginput-lightning-input-type-file](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325067/maximum-file-size-with-lightninginput-lightning-input-type-file)