# Maximum file size with lightning:input/lightning-input type=file?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I had [answered this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274303/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-we-can-upload-for-custom-lightning-upload-not-the) more than a year back where the file size was clearly documented to be 1 MB unless chunked to increase the limit to 4 MB, while using `lightning:input` and `type="file"`.

However revisiting this for an implementation in LWC (assuming the limits would have remained same), I cannot find that same information on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) available anymore! While testing it seems the limit now is actually close to the [payload limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) of < 4MB (the actual file size that can be passed to the backend to be uploaded).

Does anyone know if there was an update on the component or there is a documentation available which speaks about the actual size limits while using the `input` component in aura or lwc?

Comment: Are you talking about uploading to Salesforce, or just how big a file it can theoretically handle?

Comment: The latter. I know (I think) it can only handle < 4 MB. But what I am looking is for a solid documentation around it (I had quoted that from the docs last year in my other answer but now it's gone), so that client can make decisions accordingly. It's just a use case where we ended up using `input` instead of `file-upload` so that you know.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am looking for the limit that the component can accommodate and pass it back on to the controller for the file to be uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit on the file size, which is why there's no documentation on such a limit; the component uses an `input` to provide the file selecting functionality. Here's a quick example I wrote up for you:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedFileSize" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <lightning:input type="file" onchange="{!c.show}" label="File" />
    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.selectedFileSize}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    show: function(component, event, helper) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
            component.set("v.selectedFileSize", fileReader.result.length);
        });
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(event.getSource().get("v.files")[0]);
    }
})
```

With an example where I read a 194MB file into this binary string:

[image: Reading 194MB file into memory]

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I hadn't literally tried it myself. While I will do this as a quick test, but do you know if this is same for LWC as well?

Comment: @JayantDas Yes, the component is actually LWC under the covers.

Comment: Actually are you able to pass this file back to the controller and get it saved? What I heard from my team was that that's where the issue was encountered and anything > 4 MB wasn't going through.

Comment: @JayantDas No, the component to server limit is about 3MB (4MB of base64 encoded data). If you need to upload large files to Salesforce, you would use lightning:fileUpload (2GB limit).

Comment: Yes, that's what was the piece of information I was looking for if that's documented. I would imagine the payload docs referenced in my question is then what should be the reference here.